# Replacing JWSDP jar files with up-to-date equivalents from Maven repo

Tags: java, maven-2

I inherited an old project that uses JWSDP, and would like to upgrade it to Maven 2 and Java 6.

The project uses the following JWSDP jar files:

- jwsdp-jax-qname-1.5.jar
- jwsdp-jaxrpc-api-1.5.jar
- jwsdp-jaxrpc-impl-1.5-patched-1.10.jar
- jwsdp-jaxrpc-spi-1.5.jar
- jwsdp-namespace-1.5.jar
- jwsdp-relaxngDatatype-1.5.jar
- jwsdp-saaj-api-1.5.jar
- jwsdp-saaj-impl-1.5.jar
- jwsdp-xalan-1.5.jar
- jwsdp-xercesImpl-1.5.jar
- jwsdp-xsdlib-1.5.jar

As far as I understand, the up-to-date equivalents for these jars should be part of Glassfish , but which ones exactly do I need, and are they available in a Maven 2 repository?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to upgrade to the JWSPD 1.6 versions of the given artifacts, you'll need the following dependencies (that you can find in http://mvnrepository.com/):

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jax-qname</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.rpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrpc-spi</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3_01</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>namespace</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>relaxngDatatype</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>xsdlib</artifactId>
    <version>20050614</version>
  </dependency>
```

But note that there is no further development of JWSPD 1.6. The replacement stack is Metro which is part of GlassFish v3.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't help much.

Comment: Well, this is what you asked for. And without more details, I can't help more.